# Field not showing on layout while using Lightning Record form

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

UniformContractingLWC.html

```
    <lightning-card title="Contract Terms">
        <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
            <lightning-record-form 
            record-id={recordId} 
            object-api-name={objectApiName}
            columns="1" 
            mode="view"
            layout-type="Compact" 
            fields={fields} 
            onsuccess={handleSuccess}
            >
        </lightning-record-form>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```
UniformContractingLWC.js

    import { getDataConnectorSourceFields } from 'lightning/analyticsWaveApi';
    import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
    
    import CONTRACT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c.Contract_Terms__c';
    import STATUS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c.Apttus_QPApprov__Approval_Status__c';
    import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c.Opportunity_Owner__c';
    export default class AccountRecordForm extends LightningElement {
        @api recordId;
        @api objectApiName;
        fields = [CONTRACT_FIELD,STATUS_FIELD,NAME_FIELD];
        // console.log(CONTRACT_FIELD);
        handleSuccess(event){
            // this.recordId = event.detail.id;
            
            console.log(event.detail.id);
        }
    }
```

I am trying to show Contract_Terms__c, Apttus_QPApprov__Approval_Status__c and Opportunity_Owner__c but it is not showing on the page, while I used same code to show standard field of standard object it worked fine.

OutPut

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use layout-type="Full" in lightnin-record-form tag.